# Figure out what type of object that is passed to a SaveChanges method

Tags: c#, entity-framework, object

Using entity framework I'm overriding the SaveChanges method.

But I can't figure out a good solution to determine if the object derives from my base class or not. If it does, I want to call a method from the base class.

I have objects like this

```
public class BaseClass : EntityData { 
  public void DoSomething() { … }
}
public class B : BaseClass  { … }
public class C : BaseClass  { … }
public class D : EntityData { … }
```

In my SaveChanges method I'd like to do something like this:

```
public override int SaveChanges() {
   var changedEntitles = ChangeTracker.Entries().Where
   (_ => _.State == EntityState.Added || _.State == EntityState.Modified);
   foreach (var obj in changedEntitles)  {
       if( "obj is of type baseClass ") {  <---- need some help here
           obj.DoSomething();   <--- and here.
       }
   }
   return base.SaveChanges();
}
```

I need class B & C is supposed to: DoSomething(), class D should be ignored.

Hope you can help me.

Comment: Can you tell us what exactly are you trying to achieve with that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you to check for its type using `is` to avoid unnecessary cast.

```
if(obj.Entity is BaseClass) {
    ((BaseClass)obj).DoSomething();
}
```

Comment: If I do this, I get a message:
The given expression is never of the provided ('BaseClass') type.

Comment: Oh I see, take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15012621/how-to-get-original-entity-from-changetracker to check how to create you entity type. That happens because of the constraints inside EF

Comment: Thank you.
    if(obj.Entity is BaseClass) made it work